# Problem with battery power circuit

Tags: power, low-power, battery-operated, circuits

I am a 14 years old  boy and I am currently making a MacroPad with a 3.7V battery and a charging circuit but powering the circuit with a battery does not seem to work. I also have made some modification by adding a power selection circuit which I think may help but I am unsure if they will really help.Also, At VBAT and GND, on the old circuit, there is exactly what it should (between 3.7V and 4.2V) but at the 3.3V pin of the voltage regulator there is about 2V instead of 3.3V but idk why. Can somebody help me with my problem and check my schematics for possible errors?

**The Schematics BEFORE change:**
[image: The Schematics BEFORE change]

**The Schematics AFTER change:**
[image: The Schematics AFTER change]

Comment: What do you measure between VBAT and circuit GND with connected battery? Other hints not related to the problem: Change R1 and R2 to higher values (10..100 kohm) to not drain the battery that fast. Add a pullup resistor and a capacitor to GND at the EN pin of the ESP32.

Comment: At VBAT and GND, on the old circuit, there is exactly what it should (between 3.7V and 4.2V) but at the 3.3V pin of the voltage regulator there is about 2V instead of 3.3V but idk why.

Comment: The AMS1117 contains an NPN transistor in the output stage. This topology can reach a dropout voltage (minimum between VIN and VOUT) of 1.2 V. So the voltages you see on the 3V3 line are plausible. There are regulators with PNP or PFET output stage with much lower dropout voltages.

Comment: So I should use another LDO ?

Comment: Yes, look for dropout around 0.2 V and 0.5 A peak. Some regulators are slow, so a large C3 (47 uF tantalum) helps if you use WiFi, where short periods of high current can be expected.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help!